# How do I know which spokes to get for my wheel?

Tags: maintenance, spokes

I have a [hybrid bike](https://www.evanscycles.com/pinnacle-cobalt-three-2015-hybrid-bike-EV207278) and under description for Spokes it says "Stainless PG"...but when I look for spokes there are a multitude of sizes, thicknesses, butted, double-butted, etc.!

How do I know what to get for my bike to replace a broken spoke?

Comment: PG = Plain Gauge

Comment: Thanks @andy256 :)
That answers part of it...but what about the length of spoke?  Is it simplest just to measure a spoke?  Do spoke lengths vary around the wheel according to pattern?

Comment: Spoke length is apt to vary on the left side vs the right.  (What I do when I need spokes is to take a sample to the local bike shop.)

Comment: As @Daniel suggests, take the spoke or a neighbouring spoke to your local shop. They should have a range of sizes. The other way is to take the whole wheel, and measure the length it needs. The first way is the more accurate.

Comment: Excuse my dumbness - despite reading Sheldon Brown...will all my spokes (on one side) be the same length for a standard "cross 3" pattern?

Comment: All the spokes on one side of a wheel should be the same size.

Comment: @rclocher3 - If I were to change lacing pattern (I think mine is 2x and I would have expected 3x) then I guess I need longer spokes?

Comment: I'd think so, @BlueChippy, but I've never changed the lacing pattern of a wheel before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to determine spoke length:

1. Measure against a broken or existing spoke and because this is cycling there is a special tool for it - the spoke ruler! Most LBS have them for correctly measuring spokes. If you are measuring with a standard ruler measure from the center of the J bend to the end of the spoke.

[image: Spoke Ruler]

2. Use a spoke calculator. There are a number online such as [ProWheelBuilder](http://www.prowheelbuilder.com/spokelengthcalculator) that already have a number of standard rims and hubs built in and selectable. Otherwise you need to make a number of accurate measures of your rim and hub (or search them out online).

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean by "from the center of the J-bend".  Are you  measuring the hypotenuse?