# What are the spokes of the Kona Rove ST

Tags: wheels, spokes

I have a Kona Rove ST 2019. [The specs](https://2019.konaworld.com/rove_st.cfm) only say "Spokes: Stainless Black 14g". How do I know the precise reference so I can buy some spare ones online?

Comment: I would imaging any 14g spokes would  do as long as they're long enough

Comment: So other question: how do I know which length is it? I don't know if the length is with the screwing part or not.

Comment: I think most of us don't need to stockpile spare spokes. If one does break, a bike store will be able to measure the spokes, and they are likely to have a number of common spoke lengths in store. Just for reference, the DT Aero Comp spoke is available in lengths from 194mm to 310mm (I believe in increments of 2mm). Some stores will have spoke cutters to cut down spokes to the correct length. Otherwise, they'd probably order the correct length from their distributor.

Comment: I'm leaving for a 1.5 year bike travel :)

Comment: Then that makes sense. One option is to email the wheelset manufacturer, Wilderness Trail Bikes.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [How do I know which spokes to get for my wheel?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42031/how-do-i-know-which-spokes-to-get-for-my-wheel)

Best way is to measure the hub and the rim, or at least to know hub model and rim model.

Probably quicker to take off one spoke and measure it, but please note that on the back wheel they are of different length, depending if they are on the gear side or on the non-gear side.